# which column should be indexed?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I have a below query which will hit database every one minute

```
SELECT n.notificationid ,n.notificationtype 
FROM notification n
INNER JOIN usernotification un ON n.notificationid = un.notificationid
LEFT JOIN vhctotal vt ON vt.vhcid = n.vhcid
WHERE CASE WHEN n.notificationtype = 2 THEN n.datechecked = '' ELSE to_timestamp(n.datechecked, 'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss') > NOW() - INTERVAL '30 days' END
    AND date_trunc('day', n.vhcdate::TIMESTAMP) = CURRENT_DATE
    AND un.commentstatus = 0
    AND un.userid = 30427
    OR (
        un.commentstatus = 1
        AND un.updateddatetime > current_timestamp - interval '5 minutes'
        )
```

The above query taking a bit long time to execute. when I check those tables Indexing not done properly.

I would like to create indices for those tables. 
Should I have to create a index for the columns which are used in `WHERE` clause ?
Does it give better performance ? Please suggest .

Edit :

```
QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=25.96..2136.39 rows=1 width=237) (actual time=49.911..49.911 rows=0 loops=1)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  Join Filter: (vt.vhcid = n.vhcid)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  ->  Hash Join  (cost=25.96..2089.81 rows=1 width=163) (actual time=49.908..49.908 rows=0 loops=1)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        Hash Cond: (un.notificationid = n.notificationid)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        Join Filter: ((CASE WHEN ((n.notificationtype)::text = '2'::text) THEN ((n.datechecked)::text = ''::text) ELSE (to_timestamp((n.datechecked)::text, 'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss'::text) > (now() - '30 days'::interval)) END AND (date_trunc('day'::text, (n.vhcdate)::timestamp without time zone) = ('now'::cstring)::date) AND (un.commentstatus = 0) AND (un.userid = 30427)) OR ((un.commentstatus = 1) AND (un.updateddatetime > (now() - '00:05:00'::interval))))
        Rows Removed by Join Filter: 26406                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        ->  Seq Scan on usernotification un  (cost=0.00..528.36 rows=26136 width=36) (actual time=0.009..3.937 rows=26406 loops=1)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        ->  Hash  (cost=18.76..18.76 rows=576 width=127) (actual time=0.420..0.420 rows=577 loops=1)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 96kB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
              ->  Seq Scan on notification n  (cost=0.00..18.76 rows=576 width=127) (actual time=0.004..0.105 rows=577 loops=1)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  ->  Seq Scan on vhctotal vt  (cost=0.00..33.48 rows=1048 width=74) (never executed)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
Total runtime: 50.033 ms
```

version: postgres-9.2.14

Comment: I would add indices on `notification.notificationtype`, `usernotification.notificationid`, and `vhctotal.vhcid`

Comment: Add `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to the front of this query to get a head start.  Without knowing your schema, all we can do is *guess*.

Comment: Please read [postgresql-performance](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info) then **[edit]** your question and provide the missing information.

Comment: hi @TimBiegeleisen , commentstatus not necessary ?

Comment: Good catch...every column in the `WHERE` clause might benefit from an index.  As others have said, you should use `EXPLAIN` here to see what Postgres is actually doing behind the scenes.

Comment: sorry, i dont know how to analyse the EXPLAIN ANALYZE results @TimBiegeleisen can you tell me how to anayse?

Comment: Should I have to create a index for the columns which are used in WHERE clause ? @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: @King_Fisher Yes, that should generally help.

Comment: I wouldn't classify 50 milliseconds as "a bit long". How fast do you need that to be? An index on `notification` will hardly be of any use as it only contains 577 rows. Also: which Postgres version is that? The hash join in 50 ms for just one row seems a bit strange.

Comment: postgres-9.2.14 @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: If those 50 milliseconds are indeed too slow for some reason it's worth testing your query with the current version 9.6 There were many performance improvement in the later versions that this query might benefit from

Comment: How index can be determined from query basis from query analyser?